# Limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2-2x+2\ln(1+x)}{x^3}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I am trying to find this limit: $$L=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2-2x+2\ln(1+x)}{x^3}$$
I used L'Hopital rule then
$$L=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2x-2+\frac{2}{x+1}}{3x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2x^2+2x-2x-2+2}{3x^2(x+1)}=\frac{2}{3}$$
My question is, how to evaluate this limit without using series. Thank you for your time.

Comment: did you mean without using L'Hospital? or what do you mean by not using series?

Comment: @mrtechtroid thank you, i used L'H and I know it can be evaluated by series. I want to find the way ro evaluate without L'H or series, just used basic limits.

Comment: Your question amounts to proving without such techniques$$\ln(1+x)\in x-\frac12x^2+\frac13x^3-o(x^3).$$

Comment: For small $t$,$$2t-2+\frac{2}{1+t}-2t^2=\frac{-2t^3}{1+t}\in O(t^3).$$Integrating from $0$ to a small $x$,$$x^2-2x+2\ln(1+x)-\frac23x^3\in O(x^4)\subseteq o(x^3)\implies\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2-2x+2\ln(1+x)}{x^3}=\frac23.$$That honours the _letter_ of your requirements, but does it honour the _spirit_ of them, or do you feel it's still "cheating"?